# Facing issue in running multiple emulators with AOSP

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, android-virtual-device

**Problem overview:**

After building AOSP with custom emulator(updated default.xml), facing error in executing multiple emulators simultaneously

**Command:**

Shell1: 
 emulator -port  -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -qemu -device ,addr=,size=

Shell2: (same command to up second emulator)
 emulator -port  -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -qemu -device ,addr=,size=

**Error:**

In shell1, no error is faced. Emulator runs fine.
In shell2, ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature

**Question:**

How to correctly create multiple AVDs with AOSP such that multiple emulators can work simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

With "-read-only" could run multiple emulators simultaneously.

Below commands worked:

Commands:

Shell1:

emulator -port  -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -read-only -qemu -device ,addr=,size=

Shell2: (same command to up second emulator)

emulator -port  -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -read-only-qemu -device ,addr=,size=

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/android-building/OUM2KMQuIc4/GRcV4z9_CQAJ